# GroupBy on ArrayList of HashMap in java

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I want to do a "group-by" on `arrayList` of `HashMap` Data structure. As my data is not fixed, so I don't have any fixed classes.
Data is shown as below.

```
[{"name":"laxman","state":"Karnataka","Mobile":9034782882}, 
{"name":"rahul","state":"Kerala","Mobile":9034782882}, 
{"name":"laxman","state":"karnataka","Mobile":9034782882}, 
{"name":"ram","state":"delhi","Mobile":9034782882}]
```

The above keys are not fixed, So, I can't have classes for it.
Data and formulas will be dynamical. But for now, I am taking this example to understand `Stream.Collector` on this data.

Now, I want to get the count on basis of `name` and `state`,
So basically I want to group-by on name and state and want to get count.

I tried to use `Stream.Collector` but am not able to achieve what I want.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/ — the very first example shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with `Collectors.groupingBy`, using a `List` as the key of the returned `Map`:

```
Map<List<String>, Long> result = yourListOfMaps.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        m -> Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(m.get("name")), String.valueOf(m.get("state"))),
        Collectors.counting()));
```

This works well because all implementations of `List` in Java implement `hashCode` and `equals` consistently, which is a must for every class that is to be used as the key of any `Map` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do groupingBy twice once on the key and once again on the value.

```
Map<String, Map<Object, Long>> map = listOfMap.stream().flatMap(a -> a.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry<String, String>::getKey,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting())));
```

Output

```
{mobile={9034782882=4}, name={rahul=1, laxman=2, ram=1}, state={Karnataka=2, delhi=1, Kerala=1}}
```